# Dealing with angular promise using multiple controllers and one service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I a have a factory called mainService which consist of ajax functions that will be used to populate itself. This function is called in a mainController to populate mainService. Now, I used mainService in another controller and sometimes the data isn't available yet because the promise haven't been resolved. What is the best way to deal with this? Here are some codes:

```
function MainService(http, $q) {

//var deffered = $q.defer();

var svc = {
    userLoggedIn: false,
    userInfo: {},
    settings: {},
    loadingCount:0,

 getSettings: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        http.get(rootUrl + 'api/settings').success(function (data) {
            svc.settings = data;
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

 return svc;
```

in MainController:

```
mainservice.getSettings().then(function(data){
     //stuffs
});
```

in OtherController:

```
$scope.settings = mainservice.settings.usersettings;
```

The other controller is dealing with some UI so it is only run when users click something. Sometimes if user click too early an error 'can't read property usersettings of undefined' after that sometimes the error persist when user click again, sometimes it runs after the user click again, Why is that?

I can do mainservice.getSettings().then() again in OtherController but that doesn't feel like the proper way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

nb:This is the first time I asked question in stackoverflow and I am a new developer and English is my second language. Apologize in advance if something is wrong with my question/description.

Answer (score 0):

you should have the UI controls disabled until user can finally do something in the UI, or hide the UI until the data is available. both are ok i think.
for example you can disable the button with ng-disabled="dataAvailable" and in the getSettings().than(function () {dataAvaialble = true}) to enable it.
Hiding you can do with ng-show or ng-class and again based on the modal state of your scope.

The possible issue with the getSettings is that you fire a get call there every time and i guess you want to do it once in the entire application.
so the data should be cached in the MainService, so second time you should return the promise of the first call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I dont want to call getSettings() multiple times in my application. 

Yes I thought about disabling UI but I prefer it to get delayed instead. Btw, it is a modal, ideally I want it to appear only when data is available.

Comment: so use ng-class={hidden: dataLoading} or something and add a class in css called hidden that got display:none.

Comment: just to explain, your UI would be hidden while data loads, and second call should return the cached data, which you should keep in the service, so any future calls should get the data immediately. if you need more info i can explain or give an example but i got a feeling you got the idea.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I am not sure how to implement it. The promise object is only called in MainController which doesn't have any idea about the existence of OtherController (the one that controls modal). How do I do "display if user click but only if data is available, if data isn't available display after the data is available" in the OtherController. Thank you for your help!

Comment: so you could do something like returning the svc.settings in the service function, and in the other controller do a watch for the $resolved property like this: $scope.$watch('settings.$resolved', function () {
                    if (($scope.setting !== undefined) && ($scope.setting.$resolved)) {
                        //i got the data from the GET
                    }
                });

Comment: naturally in the other controller do $scope.settings = myService.getSettings(); first

Comment: and by the way, i would not use $http, i would use $resource instead which is better suited. so you can call the get via $resource('my url').get()

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is async nature of your service call. Assuming `OtherController` is a nested controller and shares scope with `MainController`. You can use a watch to check when the data is available for `OtherController` to use:

```
$scope.$watch('settings',function(newValue) {
  if(newValue) $scope.settings = newValue.usersettings;
});
```

Using `.getSettings().then()` is also ok, but you should cache the remote response else every time a new request would be made.

Another option is to use `$routeProvider` `resolve` configuration to pass this data to `MainController`. In this case the MainController will only get loaded when the settings data is available. Look at `resolve` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and example to understand how it is done.